# instantiating a javascript object from its name

Tags: javascript, oop

I am kinda implementing my own very basic MVC controller and all I want is that if I have a viewName, I want to instantiate the javascript object with the name 'viewName'. for eg.

Lets say I have an object definition as

```
function ViewABC() {}
ViewABC.prototype.init = function() {
      alert("comes here!");
};
```

now somewhere in my controller module, I get a view name as 'ViewABC'. All I want is to invoke the object with the viewName

```
function(viewName){
//check if viewName exists somewhere! initial validation
//create var viewObj = new 'viewName' here in this case it will be
//var viewObj =- new ViewABC();
//then call viewObj.init();
```

I looked into window[className] as well as this[className] but neither window or this has the function class that I have defined in the context.

Please advise.

Comment: Is ViewABC in global scope? You probably will have to namespace it. You needs to show more context.

Comment: It is in the global scope. How do I namespace it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just dumping functions in the global scope, what about this:

```
Views = Views || {}; // namespace initialization
Views['ViewABC'] = function() {};
// ...
var viewName = 'ViewABC';
var viewObj = new Views[viewName]();
```

**UPDATE**

Change the first line to:

```
window.Views = window.Views || {};
```

or if you only use it once, just:

```
Views = {};
```

Comment: pardon my naiveness to javascript, when I try to add a method, say init to the prototype, its not working

Comment: Views['ViewABC'].protoype.init = function() {
    alert("comes here!");
};

Comment: `protoype` should be `prototype`

Comment: it still gave 'cannot find variable Views'

Comment: Then you are probably not defining it within the global scope.

Comment: Or you could have added `var ` to the beginning of your original solution.

Comment: found the issue. Views didn't had a var before it. :( This now just works fine. Thanks :D\